# Is it possible / How to run gulp modules directly?

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-less, gulp-plugin

It would make sense for me to use some of gulp modules/plugins independently. E.g.: I have installed gulp-less globally (`npm install --global gulp-less`) and want to use it instead of lessc in the manner like `grunt-less -options ./my/css/folder` or `grunt less -options ./my/css/folder`. But my attempt end with an error message:

```
$ gulp less ./css/
Using gulpfile ~/temp/gulptest/gulpfile.js
Task 'less' is not in your gulpfile
Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

Ideally I also would like to use gulp plugins outside of any project as independent tools.

**How to run gulp modules outside of the build context?**

If this option is not provided: Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Put in your gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('less', function () {
  // as you wish
})
```